# E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403

Tags: android, kotlin, amazon-s3, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

There is a video hosted on Amazon S3 with Authorized-Read Access, I got above error when play video while I send S3 keys

**Log**

```
tech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error
      com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:300)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:83)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:962)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:415)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

**Code**

```
 val defaultHttpDataSourceFactory =
            DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30").apply {
                defaultRequestProperties.set("access_key", "")
                defaultRequestProperties.set(
                    "secret_key",   "" )
                defaultRequestProperties.set("bucket_name", "")
                defaultRequestProperties.set("region", "")

            }

        return ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(defaultHttpDataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(uri)
```

when check network profiler i found *request* has *headers* correctly.

Comment: could you find a solution?, i think I m stuck in same place

Comment: the solution was to generate a public link from Amazon S3 SDK and use it normally with exo-player

Comment: what do you mean by "public link"?

Comment: I had named it public but it is 'PresignedUrl', i added code as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to **generatePresignedUrl** :

add next to `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.9.2'
```

```kotlin
object AmazonS3Helper {

    fun getURI(objectName: String, s3: S3Credentials?): Uri? {
  
        val myCredentials: AWSCredentials =
            BasicAWSCredentials(s3?.accessKey, s3?.secretKey)
        val s3client: AmazonS3 = AmazonS3Client(myCredentials)
        val region = s3?.region ?: "eu-west-2"
        s3client.setRegion(com.amazonaws.regions.Region.getRegion(region))
        val request = GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(s3?.buckeName, objectName)
        val objectURL: URL = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(request)
        return Uri.parse(objectURL.toString())
    }
}
```

then use **uri**  as normal with exo-player

NOTE: S3Credentials it is just wrapper class to have S3 header values like(bucket_name, etc).